# How can I get current store details in shopify app front-end using node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing shopify public app with **node.js** and **express** and want to know that how can get the current **store details** at my **app front-end** when store admin open my app

I am getting **store details** at **back-end** side in **query_string** when store admin click on **navigation link** of my app but not able to get at **front-end** side with `jquery` or `javascripts` and I am using **express** and **ejs** view templating for **front-end**

can any one please help me out this that how to manage current store details at front-end side. Thank you

Comment: If you are getting at backend, Then why not you are able to send it to front-end as well using cookies, adding in HTML using ejs ?

Comment: at back-end side how to store in cookie in node  I already tried for set from back-end but cookies only set from front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to access store details at my shopify app front-end as following

require changes =>
use '**cookie**' npm package for storing data in cookies and also set cookie as like this in your controller

```
   const cookie = require('cookie');

  app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    const data=req.query;
    res.cookie('shop_detail',data);
});
```

get cookie from your front-end use following javascript function

```
      function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
          if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
          }
          return null;
      }
```

call this function like this

```
readCookie('shop_detail');
```